# What is the difference / relationship between permutation feature importance (PFI) and feature contribution calculation (FCC)?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

As the title suggests, I want to know what is the difference / relationship between the two 'explainability' tools - permutation feature importance (PFI), and feature contribution calculation (FCC), when evaluating the impact of features in a machine learning model?

I know that ML.Net allows use of both, they both tell you the impact each feature has within the performance of the model generation, but I don't understand what the key differences are between them. Why would both be needed?

Academic library search, google, and google scholar tells me more about what PFI is all about, but I can't find anything on FCC.

```
//PFI
// Compute the feature importance using PFI
var permutationMetrics = mlContext.Regression.PermutationFeatureImportance(model, data);

// Get the feature names from the training set
var featureNames = data.Schema.GetColumns()
                .Select(tuple => tuple.column.Name) // Get the column names
                .Where(name => name != labelName) // Drop the Label
                .ToArray();

// Write out the feature names and their importance to the model's R-squared value
for (int i = 0; i < featureNames.Length; i++)
  Console.WriteLine($" 
{featureNames[i]}\t{permutationMetrics[i].rSquared:G4}");


/////VERUS/////


//FCC

// Create a Feature Contribution Calculator
// Calculate the feature contributions for all features given trained model parameters

var featureContributionCalculator = mlContext.Model.Explainability.FeatureContributionCalculation(model.Model, model.FeatureColumn, numPositiveContributions: 11, normalize: false);

// FeatureContributionCalculatingEstimator can be use as an intermediary step in a pipeline. 
// The features retained by FeatureContributionCalculatingEstimator will be in the FeatureContribution column.

var pipeline = mlContext.Model.Explainability.FeatureContributionCalculation(model.Model, model.FeatureColumn, numPositiveContributions: 11)
    .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.OrdinaryLeastSquares(featureColumn: "FeatureContributions"));
```

I would like to write clearly, for academic purposes, the difference between them, maybe what they use to calculate the feature's importance, or the logic inside - how it is different.